# * sign in regexp forces to match a letter

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to match a word and 0 or more letters after it. I have constructed the following `RegExp`: `/test\w*/`
`\w` for any letter, `*` for zero or more match.
However it works incorrectly. It matches **testing** **tests**, but not **test** itself.
Here is the code I am using for testing:

```
console.log(new RegExp("test" + "[\\w*]").test("tests")); // true
console.log(new RegExp("test" + "[\\w*]").test("test")); // false - should be true
console.log(new RegExp("test" + "[\\w*]").test("test-")); // false
console.log(new RegExp("test" + "[\\w*]").test("testing")); // true
console.log(new RegExp("test" + "[\\w*]").test("test@")); // false
```

**Update**
The expression works exactly as I wanted in [regexr.com](http://regexr.com/)

Comment: Downvoter, comment please!

Comment: @Kobi and what would it give me?

Comment: Up vote because I hate down voters, and they are absolutely not constructive to helping.

Comment: @Mr.Student thanks, you are absolutely right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `*` inside brackets doesn't means 0 or more, its literally the char `*` to be matched.
EDITED: If you do not want to match words like `"test-"`, use the end of string anchor `$` like this:

```
console.log(new RegExp("test" + "\\w*$").test("test"));
```

Explanation on why your regex fails:

```
console.log(new RegExp("test" + "[\\w*]").test("test"));
```

Means: Match the word test, then any char that is `\w` or the char `*`, that's why other cases match and "test" doesn't matches, so your regex would match `"test*"` for instance.

Comment: It matches everything I type

Comment: can you give me an example, its not matching everything here

Comment: Change all the examples I gave in the code. It should work exactly the same, except the second one, that should be true

Comment: Well, its the correct behavior, since they are matching the word test

Comment: Are you trying to match only single words?

Comment: I want to match the word itself and if there are **any letters** after it I want them to be match either.

Comment: You are not making that clear on your question, so ill update anyway with the behavior it seams you are expecting

Answer (score 0):

`\w*` is what you meant: 0 or more letters.
However, `[\w*]` means either `\w` or (escaped character) `*`.

Check out the definition of [**bracket expression**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#POSIX_basic_and_extended) (`[]`)

Comment: I knew it, but I have no other ideas left in my mind. Rodrigo López prompted me that I was missing `$` character for end match.